# req.pramas returning null value?

Tags: node.js, http-get

I'm trying to send the version value to the console with below code using node route

```
app.get('/api/:version',function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.params.version);
});
```

But it's returning null value. I don't know where did i go wrong.

Comment: what is the route that you're calling?

Comment: In this case your route should be something like this _http://localhost:8080/api/1_